# How to display images from an email with QWebView?

Tags: html, qt, qwebview

I have an email which contains perfectly formatted html with the single exception that images are linked differently: `<img width=456 height=384 id="_x0000_i1026" src="cid:X.MA2.1374935634@aol.com" alt="cid:X.MA4.1372453963@aol.com">` the email has other parts including the image with this content id. The problem is that I dont know how to point the QWebview to the data (which I have). Is there a way to add the image to its cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but not easy.
Basically you need to:

1- provide your own `QNetworkAccessManager`-inherited class, overriding `createRequest()` to catch these links refering to `"cid"`:

```
QNetworkReply*
MyManager::createRequest (Operation op,
                 const QNetworkRequest & req,
                 QIODevice * outgoingData = 0)
{
  if (op==GetOperation && req.url().scheme() == "cid")
    return MyNetworkReply(req.url().path());
  else
    return QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(op, req, outgoingData);
}
```

2- Connect it to the webview with:

```
MyManager* manager = new MyManager;
view->page()->setNetworkAccessManager(manager);
```

3- Provide an implementation of `MyNetworkReply` which inherits from `QNetworkReply`, a `QIODevice`-class. And this is the complicated part. You need to provide at least `readData()`, `bytesAvailable()`, a constructor that sets up the reply in terms of HTTP headers, and launches the actual asynchronous read with `QTimer::singleShot()`

4- Decode the attachment (probably from `base64` if it's a picture) into a `QByteArray`  for your `MyNetworkReply::readData()` to read from that.

There's a complete example on `qt.gitorious.org` written by [Qt Labs](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs) developers in the Qt 4.6 days. They display an internally generated PNG, not an external mail attachment, but the general steps are as described above. See:

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/graphics-dojo/blobs/master/url-rendering/main.cpp

However this code has a flaw with Qt-4.8. in the constructor for `RendererReply`, when it does:

```
open(ReadOnly|Unbuffered);
```

this should be:

```
open(ReadOnly);
```

otherwise webkit never reads the entire data and displays the broken picture icon.

Comment: As a sidenote to anyone else that may try this: the cache is NOT used unless you explicitly call it yourself. Meaning, you still have to implement a QNetworkAccessManager and not just a new cache object. Although, for me the `Unbuffered` flag does not cause the error this answer said that it does. Still, much gratitude for the help.

Comment: Although, I noticed that I had images not fully loading when I omitted the `setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,QVariant("image/png"));` section.